# How to bypass a changed layer and jump to the cache of a later layer

Tags: docker

I have a dockerfile with many layers. I build the images up to layer `n` where the build fails. Then I change something in the code such that it fixes the build issue of layer `n`. I know that code base and I know that this particular change doesn't make any difference in the functionality of layer `n-m`, but this layer does get rebuilt because it's based on that code base. I would like to avoid this rebuild, and instead jump to the cache of layer `n-1` and continue the build from there. Is this possible?

If I do `docker build --cache-from IMAGE_ID_OF_LAYER_n_1`, looks like `--cache-from` gets ignored and the build starts from layer `n-m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible.  The [Docker build cache](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache) works by calculating a hash from the previous image and the actions in this step, where that includes the actual contents of any `ADD`ed or `COPY`ed files.

For example, if you have

```sh
FROM some/base         # 00000000
RUN step-l             # 11111111
RUN step-m --option-a  # 22222222
RUN step-n             # 33333333
```

then what gets cached for the last line is "image 22222222, plus `RUN step-n`, produces image 33333333".  But if you then change

```sh
FROM some/base         # 00000000
RUN step-l             # 11111111
RUN step-m --option-b  # 44444444
RUN step-n
```

then there's nothing in the cache for "image 44444444, plus `RUN step-n`".

If your steps are very different you might be able to take advantage of a multi-stage build

```sh
FROM some/base AS build-m
RUN step-m --option-a

FROM some/base AS build-n
RUN step-n

FROM some/base
COPY --from=build-m /opt/m /opt/m
COPY --from=build-n /opt/n /opt/n
```

Then even if you change the `RUN step-m`, the `RUN step-n` can still be cached.  The final assembly would still have to be repeated but that's just copying files.  (Imagine a setup where one step is running `webpack` to precompile a browser application and you just need to copy its `dist` tree in, for example.)